# Office Add-ins: Any way to have one always running?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I have an idea for an Office/PowerPoint Add-in. Most of the ones I've seen (and what is sampled in the documentation) are add-in actions that are triggered by a button click in the ribbon, or triggered by an action the sidebar. However, I need the Add-in to be running from the moment PowerPoint opens.

Is there a way to have a add-in that is running in the background? Listening for events? My idea involves catching when the slide changes - but I need this to happen when the PowerPoint is in Presenter view.

Is this currently possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Ask google to tell you about "powerpoint vba events" (sans the quote marks).

Comment: @SteveRindsberg That would only work with VBA scripts or classic-addins; not the new style addins, thoug? Thanks for the hint though, it'd work with one of my ideas with some, I'm sure but not exactly a modern solution.

Comment: At present, the "modern" approach  is badly crippled. Personally, I'd prefer to stick with what works until "modern" does.